# How to do "Nested" object destructuring

Tags: javascript

```
const {A:{B}} = {A:{B:"C"}}

console.log(B); // <-- "C" is printed.
console.log(A); // <-- Error!
```

But is there a way to somehow console.log(A) without breaking expression like so:

```
const obj = {A:{B:"C"}};

const {A} = obj;
const {A:{B}} = obj;

console.log(B); // <-- "C" is printed.
console.log(A); // <-- Works obviously.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
const { A, A:{ B } } = {A :{ B:"C" } }
```

or

```
const { A } = { A :{ B:"C" } }
const { B } = A;
```